# How can I include this as an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to draw a jack-o-lantern, and I can't figure out how to apply these arguments I defined... What function is there for me to draw random shapes I've created?

```
from turtle import*

pumpkin_size=input("Would you like your pumpkin to be tall, fat, or small? ")
turtle_1=Turtle()
turtle_2=Turtle()


def tall_pumpkin():
    color("orange")
    shape("circle")
    shapesize(20,16,5)
    fillcolor("orange")

def fat_pumpkin():
    color("orange")
    shape("circle")
    shapesize(15,18,5)

def small_pumpkin():
    color("orange")
    shape("circle")
    shapesize(14,14,5)

interpret_size = {
    "fat": "fat_pumpkin",
    "tall": "tall_pumpkin",
    "small": "small_pumpkin",
    }


exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few fixes will solve the issue:

```
from turtle import *

canvas = Screen()
canvas.setup(400,200)

pumpkin_size = raw_input("Would you like your pumpkin to be tall, fat, or small? ")
turtle = Turtle()

print 'selection {}'.format(pumpkin_size)


def tall_pumpkin():
    turtle.color("orange")
    turtle.shape("circle")
    turtle.shapesize(20,16,5)
    turtle.fillcolor("orange")


def fat_pumpkin():
    turtle.color("orange")
    turtle.shape("circle")
    turtle.shapesize(15,18,5)


def small_pumpkin():
    turtle.color("orange")
    turtle.shape("circle")
    turtle.shapesize(14,14,5)

interpret_size = {
    "fat": fat_pumpkin,
    "tall": tall_pumpkin,
    "small": small_pumpkin,
    }

interpret_size[pumpkin_size]()
canvas.exitonclick()
```

First you need to declare a canvas object, Then use `"fat": fat_pumpkin` and not `"fat": "fat_pumpkin"` now you can call `interpret_size[pumpkin_size]()` which will call the function at the key from the input.

One more thing is to use your instance of `turtle` and set it's own attributes like `color` or `shape`.

- for python3 user `input()`